# Creating instance for NSManagedObject Class using Restkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, restkit

how can i create an instance for NSmanagedObject Class which i am created using core data model. I have another class which is the subclass of NSObject. I want to create an object for NSManageObject Class. how can i do that. Is it like the normal way that we create the instance for NSobject class like

ClassB.m //ClassB is NSObject Class

```
ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc]init]; //ClassA is NSmanagedObject Class
```

or is there any way to do that???

i am not using this code([Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-CJBDBHCB)) for creating instance

```
NSManagedObject *newEmployee = [[NSManagedObject alloc]

            initWithEntity:employeeEntity

            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

i would like to know, is there any way to create an object similar to the above code using restkit

Note: i am using Restkit for creating object instance and mapping.

Thanks

Comment: Just have a look at "Creating and Deleting Managed Objects" in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but i am using restkit for object mapping. so i need to know how to create instance using Restkit model

Comment: Then you should state your problem more precisely. The question does not mention RestKit.

Comment: @Martin: i have editted my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Restkit you can use the static method object on the class you want to create. In your example

> `[ClassA object]`

would return you an instantiated object.

Just be sure to import the correct headers:

> `#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>`

instead of

> `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`

Comment: what happens with this object? Is it then directly in the core data model?

Comment: you get a reference to it. It is just a wrapper to id object = [[self alloc] initWithEntity:[self entity] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]];
    return [object autorelease]; So you should still save it explicity (that's what i do anyway)

Comment: Okey, thank you. Im working with RestKit at the moment and I think its not that easy to get the information I need sometimes...

Comment: @Jeroen Coupé: can i pass the NSManagedClass object as an argument. i just want to use the same object for sending and receiving data.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. If you still have the reference to the object you can just update the content of the object and save to the database and your object will be persisted.

Comment: That object method doesn't seem to exist in what will be the 0.11 release of RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want to instantiate an NSManagedObject via alloc/init.  You should use `NSEntityDescription`'s `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.  Something like:

```
ClassA *obj = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClassA"
    inManagedObjectContext:context]; // ClassA is NSManagedObject Class
```

In order to have a `NSManagedObjectContext`, you also need an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, and an `NSManagedObjectModel`, etc.  Yeah, it's complex.  [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321670426) really helped me get my head around Core Data; I recommend it wholeheartedly.

See the [Core Data Programming Guide section on creating and deleting managed objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html).  Actually, while you're there, I'd recommend reading the entire [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1).  Core Data is amazing and powerful, but it is complex; you really want to know what you're doing.

**Update**: The fact that you're using RestKit might change what I said above.  It may be that RestKit has it's own API for doing Core Data stuff, I'm not sure.  Maybe check the docs.